# How to transform '2 levels ParamUty' class in nested cross-validation of mlr3proba?

Tags: r, machine-learning, mlr3

For survival analysis, I am using `mlr3proba` package of R.
My dataset consists of 39 features(both continuous and factor, which i converted all to integer and numeric) and target (time & status).
I want to tune hyperparameter: num_nodes, in `Param_set`. 
 This is a `ParamUty` class parameter with default value: `32,32`.
 so I decided to transform it.
I wrote the code as follows for hyperparamters optimization of `surv.deephit` learner using 'nested cross-validation' (with 10 inner and 3 outer folds).

```
#task definition
task.mlr <- TaskSurv$new(id = "id", backend = main.dataset, event = 'status', time = 'time')

#learner definition
dh.learner <- lrn('surv.deephit') 
   
#resampling method
resampling <- rsmp('cv', folds =10)
  
#tuner method
tuner <- tnr('random_search')

#measure method
measure <- msr('surv.harrellC')

#termination method
terminator <- trm('stagnation')

#search_space definition(for num_nodes)
search_space <- ps(num_nodes = p_fct(list(c(32,64,128,256)), trafo = function(x) c(sample(x,1), sample(x,1))))

#To check search_space
generate_design_random(search_space,10)$transpose()
```

When I ran the last lines of code with transpose, it demonstrated a list of num_nodes each contained a paired categories, as follows:

```
[[1]]$num_nodes
[1] 64 128

[[2]]$num_nodes
[1] 32 256

...
```

then I wrote the following code:

```
#defining autotuner
at <- AutoTuner$new(dh.learner, resampling, measure, terminator, tuner, search_space)

#outer cross validation
resampling_outer <- rsmp('cv', folds = 3)

# nested resampling
nest_rsm <- resample(task.mlr, at, resampling_outer)
```

But in the result of nested resampling, instead of pair of nodes, it shows num_nodes as `c(32,64,128,256)`. Something like this:

```
    num_nodes 
   c(32,64,128,256)
    num_nodes
   c(32,64,128,256)
   ...
```

How can I transform 'Param_Uty' with 2 levels(eg. `32,64`)? 
Honestly I have heavily searched this topic, and after all I did not find appropriate answer, so i appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi thanks for using mlr3proba. I have actually just finished writing a tutorial that answers exactly this question! It covers training, tuning, and evaluating the neural networks in mlr3proba. For your specific question, the relevant part of the tutorial is this:

```
library(paradox)
search_space = ps(
  nodes = p_int(lower = 1, upper = 32),
  k = p_int(lower = 1, upper = 4)
)

search_space$trafo = function(x, param_set) {
  x$num_nodes = rep(x$nodes, x$k)
  x$nodes = x$k = NULL
  return(x)
}
```

Here I am tuning over two new hyper-parameters, one which represents number of nodes per layer and one which is the number of layers, I then create a transformation that combines them into the desired hyper-parameter, `num_nodes`.

You should be able to apply this to your example.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I implemented your code, it produced this optimized parameter as (abstract):  nodes=23, k=2, and etc. The output does not show num_nodes directly. Does it return the num_nodes internally via trafo but does not show it in the output?  And also based on your answer, it seems my code in the question is also functional, as in the output it shows all possible num_nodes as c(32 64, 128, 256), and in the function it select two of them randomly as eg. c(32,64), right?

Comment: Yes I believe you are correct. Put this way: the output shows what we are tuning over, which in this case are the 'pseudo' parameters (nodes, k), whereas what goes into the model is num_nodes. Your method does work but I don't recommend it because you have two sources of randomness (random search and `sample`). So it's better to set-up a grid instead and then randomly search over this. If you're interested I just put the full tutorial up: https://towardsdatascience.com/neural-networks-for-survival-analysis-in-r-1e0421584ab?source=friends_link&sk=e978a1b30a4da3370bea930e169326f3